# Gutenberg Block Rendering from JSON

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-gutenberg, gutenberg-blocks

I am trying to make custom Gutenberg Blocks through a plugin. Everything is going smooth the only issue is when I select my block from the blocks menu, it just pastes the JSON on the front. What I rather want is to render this JSON to make blocks.

I am fetching blocks' content from an API. I am attaching my code as well.

```
function makeBlock(block, category){
    var jsonBlock = {
        "__file": "wp_export",
        "version": 2,
        "content": ""}
        ;
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: document.location.origin+"/blocknets/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php",
        data: { 
            'action': 'makeBlocks',
            'id': block.id
        },
        dataType: "json",
        encode: true,
    }).done(function (resp) {
        // console.log(resp);
        jsonBlock.content = resp.data.content;
    });




    ( function ( blocks, element, data, blockEditor ) {
        var el = element.createElement,
            registerBlockType = blocks.registerBlockType,
            useSelect = data.useSelect,
            useBlockProps = blockEditor.useBlockProps;
    //  debugger;
        registerBlockType( 'custom-blocks/'+category+'-'+block.id, {
            apiVersion: 2,
            title: block.name,
            icon: 'megaphone',
            category: category,
            edit: ()=>{return jsonBlock.content},
            save: () => null
        } );
    } )(
        window.wp.blocks,
        window.wp.element,
        window.wp.data,
        window.wp.blockEditor
    );
}
```

[image]

Purple Highlighted is my plugin, and Yellow is what it prints out.

What I rather want is to render this JSON. If I just paste this JSON into code editor it would look like this.

[image]

Can anyone help me out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to render all the blocks by using the following edit function:

```
    edit: ()=>{
      window.wp.data.dispatch( 'core/block-editor' ).insertBlocks( window.wp.blocks.parse( jsonBlock.content));
      return null;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

The `jsonBlock.content` displayed in the Editor view is serialized block content. The first step is to use [parse()](https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/reference-guides/packages/packages-block-serialization-default-parser/#parse) to transform the content into valid blocks. Next, to render the blocks I found [RawHTML](https://github.com/WordPress/gutenberg/blob/5185ffc964b4a8bf77ee72da146598205c41620b/packages/element/src/raw-html.js) can be used to render innerHTML from the block content. The `<RawHTML/>` component uses [dangerouslySetInnerHTML](https://reactjs.org/docs/dom-elements.html#dangerouslysetinnerhtml) as seen commonly in React to render inner HTML content.  Eg:

**Edit()**

```js
const { parse } = wp.blockSerializationDefaultParser;
const { RawHTML } = wp.element;

export default function Edit({ attributes, setAttributes }) {

    // Example of serialized block content to mimic resp.data.content data
    var content = "<!-- wp:paragraph --><p>paragraph one</p><!-- /wp:paragraph --><!-- wp:paragraph --><p>then two</p><!-- /wp:paragraph -->";

    // Parse the serialized content into valid blocks using parse from @wordpress/block-serialization-default-parser
    var blocks = parse(content);

    // Iterate over each block to render innerHTML within RawHTML that sets up dangerouslySetInnerHTML for you..
    return blocks.map((block, index) => <RawHTML key={index}>{block.innerHTML}</RawHTML>);
}
```

*Nb. The example covers parsing and displaying block content in the Editor, it does not cover saving the content, as your existing save() function is set to null.*